# How compare value of BIT column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I have a bit column (for example, 'Column').

How can I compare the value of this column to just any number?

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 'Column' = 5`

After executing the above query, I get an error message: the operator does not exist: bit = integer

Comment: `5` is not a binary digit I've ever heard of. Do you mean `B'101'`?

Comment: Please edit your post because the query you show is syntactically impossible.  Bottom line is to either cast the `"Column"` to `int` or the literal `5` to `bit(4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the value to compre to bit

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (Column1 bit(4))
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE Column1 = 5::BIT(4)
```

| column1 |
| --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BATT7EAf)

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a bit field to a number in PostgreSQL, you should use the bit literal syntax. You can alter your query as follows to compare the value 5 to a bit column named "Column":

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE "Column" = B'101'; -- B'101' represents the bit value 5
```

This query will produce a list of the rows where the 'Column' field's bit representation is 5.

Hope it works :)